# Excel VBA - copy and paste rows, but ignore if blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code set up to copy all non-blank rows from a worksheet and copy to another. However, if the sheet is blank then it copies the header row rather than ignoring it - not sure how to fix this!

Code I am using is...

```
Sub cpynpst()
Dim sh4 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh4 = Sheets("Staines - H Lettings")
Set sh5 = Sheets("All Lets")
lr = sh4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh4.Range("A2:A" & lr)
rng.EntireRow.Copy sh5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
End Sub
```

The module is repeated for each individual worksheet and runs on a new module to loop them all. This is copying fine, but if the sheet is blank and only contains a header row, the header copies and doesn't ignore the empty sheet.

```
Sub alllets()

Call Module1.cpynpst
Call Module1.cpynpst1
Call Module1.cpynpst2
Call Module1.cpynpst3
Call Module1.cpynpst4
Call Module1.cpynpst5
Call Module1.cpynpst6
Call Module1.cpynpst7
Call Module1.cpynpst8
Call Module1.cpynpst9
Call Module1.cpynpst10

End Sub
```

Comment: If the sheet is blank, then the value of `lr` will be 1. So `rng` will be `A2:A1` (aka `A1:A2`). So use an IF statement - `If lr > 2 Then..`

Comment: @CLR You mean `If lr > 1 Then`.

Comment: @Vbasic2008 - yup, absolutely. @ ffc2004 - glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRowSource As Long, LastRowDestination As Long

'Loop all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
    'Check worksheet name. Do not copy from worksheet named "All Lets". "All Lets" is the destination
        If .Name <> "All Lets" Then
            'Find the last row of the source worksheet
            LastRowSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'Check if the last row is greater than 1, this means that it has data
            If LastRowSource > 1 Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Lets")
                    'Find the last row of the destination worksheet
                    LastRowDestination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    'Copy & paste the data in the next empty cell
                    ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRowSource).Copy .Range("A" & LastRowDestination + 1)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```